Is it possible to adjust the sensitivity of the zoom in the 3D viewport when Zoom Method is set on Dolly?
In Blender Preferences > Navigation,  we can easily adjust the Orbit Sensitivity, but there is no setting such as "Zoom Sensitivity".
I use Zoom Method set on Dolly, with Zoom Axis set on Vertical, so I can zoom in and out by moving my mouse up and down, as long as I hold a key down. But I want to modify how much up and down I have to move my mouse to reach a certain zoom level.
So is it possible and how can I adjust the sensitivity of the zoom in the 3D viewport when Zoom Method is set on Dolly ?
